# Dual monitors on Odin

Tags: desktop, release-odin, monitors

I know this is probably a Gnome thing but is there a way to have both monitors switch to another desktop instead of just the main display?
I know there is an extension for Gnome that allows this but I hesitate to try to install extensions on Pantheon. I installed Pantheon Tweaks but it dont like just installing ppa's tp solve things.

Comment: That worked! Thank you!
But will it stay persistent through a reboot or login?

Comment: Yes, the setting will persist. Be sure to use *comments* rather than answers when asking follow-up questions 

Comment: Oops. Didnt realize I did that. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can do this via Terminal with the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter workspaces-only-on-primary false
```

I cannot test this right now (the work machines are stock Ubuntu), but this generally the solution with Gnome-based desktops.